# Make PDF from libreoffice impress handout

Tags: libreoffice, pdf

Is there any way to 'print to pdf' the handout from libreoffice? I can print it in a normal printer, but I need it as a pdf file.

As an edit: because I'm working on a deadline (this is to make a poster) I've decided to go to `Format - Page` and selected A2 as the size, added text boxes - to make a 'fake' handout, but it's less than ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose File/Print... On the first tab, choose "Handouts". On the last tab, called "Options", select "Print to file...". Press the "Print to file" button and enter a file name. Done!

Comment: Sorry I'm probably being stupid but I can't find the options/print to file

Comment: Or more probably, you have a different version of LibreOffice. Mine is 4.3.3.2. The print dialog should have four tabs - General, LibreOffice Impress, Page lay-out, and Options. On the last tab, there is the option to print to a file.

Comment: And that's exactly what I was looking for. Either I'm stupid, or that was hard to find. Probably both ;) Old guides told me that one of the printer options should be 'print to file', so I thought they just scrapped this option.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in the `File` menu of Libre Writer called **Export as PDF**.
Once you export, open it again and print.

Comment: I want to export the handouts though, and I can only find the options for printing the handout to either a real printer, or export individual slides as a PDF (so different pages in the PDF). What I want is the 'handout' view, where there's 6 slides or whatever on one page.